# color only some value(s) in a list in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-styles

I have a dataframe  each cell in one of the columns contains a list in the format `[2,19,25,39,49]`. I would like to color individual values in each list that are contained in a list `common = [7,9,16,18,19,20,21,25,33,35,38,40,49]`, so in the example 19,25 and 49 should be colored differently or that is what I would like to achieve.
I have tried using:

```
def color_common(x):
   if x in common:
     color='green'
   else:
     color='black'
```

I get the response, "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous".
if I use x.any(), I get "Result has shape: (6,)
Expected shape:   (5, 6)"
I don't understand the expected shape comment nor the ambiguous truth and where/how to apply any() or all().
Is it possibile to color  components of a list.I manage to color whole cells or the contents of a cell quite easily. I have not styled a Panda dataframe before hence possibily the 'dumbness of my question

Comment: sorry command is results.style.apply(color_common)

Comment: I have tried using ,without success , the following to solve the ambiguity:            def color_common(x):
    if x in common:
        for i in range(len(results.iloc[0][0])):
            for num in results.iloc[i][0]:
                if x == num:
                    color='green'
                else:
                    color='black'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert *common* (your list) to a regex pattern:

```
pat = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(map(str, common)) + r')\b')
```

(*import re* required).

Then define the following formatting function:

```
def myFmt(txt):
    return pat.sub(r'<font color="#ff0000">\1</font>', repr(txt))
```

(I assumed that the required formatting is "color red", but change it
according to what you want.)

And to present your DataFrame formatted your way, run:

```
df.style.format(myFmt)
```

To test it, I created a DataFrame containing:

```
              A             B
0    [1, 9, 25]  [10, 18, 77]
1    [3, 7, 22]   [4, 21, 27]
2  [11, 16, 29]  [24, 38, 41]
```

and got the following result:

[image]

Note: If you want to apply this formatting to selected columns only,
pass *subset* parameter with a list of "wanted" columns.

Comment: Thank you. Works brilliantly. Not sure how to pass the subset parameter. I will need to think that out.

Comment: *subset* is a parameter of *df.style.format*.
Try e.g. *df.style.format(myFmt, subset=['A'])* to format only column "A".

Comment: Works exactly as I had hoped I could achieve. I would have not got there without your information and solution