# Jupyter notebook shows a different output when calling display for Pandas DataFrames (Python). It does not compile HTML codes within each cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, pandas-styles

I am using Jupyter Notebook and Pandas DataFrame to look through some 3D and 4D matrices.
I am using what **@Attack68** has replied in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68880224/how-to-make-pandas-dataframe-python-to-display-each-cell-in-a-two-dimensional/68895272#68895272).

The problem is, when I use only one jupyter cell for making a DataFrame, without calling "display" function, it works just fine, and will run HTML codes perfectly. You can see an example here:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [
    [[1]],
    [[1.0,2.0],[2.0,4.0],[8.0,3.0],[9.0,7.0]],
    [[0.487],[1.532],[1.544],[1.846]],
    [[3.0]],
    [[3.0]],
    [[-1]],
]
    
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [(pd.DataFrame(x)
        .style
        .hide_index()
        .hide_columns()
        .set_table_attributes('class="matrix"')
        .to_html()
     ) for x in data]
], dtype="object")
df.style.set_table_styles([
    {"selector": ".matrix", "props": "position: relative;"},
    {"selector": ".matrix:before, .matrix:after", 
     "props":  'content: ""; position: absolute; top: 0; border: 1px solid #000; width: 6px; height: 100%;'
    },
    {"selector": ".matrix:before", "props": "left: -0px; border-right: -0;"},
    {"selector": ".matrix:after", "props": "right: -0px; border-left: 0;"}
])
```

Which will result in :
[Intended_Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcpp1.png) (my reputation is not enough to use inline image. Sorry about inconvenience)

However, the problem is, as soon as I add display function to display the table, it stops compiling the HTML codes and showing the matrices itself, and returns only the codes instead as the DataFrame cells.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [
    [[1]],
    [[1.0,2.0],[2.0,4.0],[8.0,3.0],[9.0,7.0]],
    [[0.487],[1.532],[1.544],[1.846]],
    [[3.0]],
    [[3.0]],
    [[-1]],
]
    
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [(pd.DataFrame(x)
        .style
        .hide_index()
        .hide_columns()
        .set_table_attributes('class="matrix"')
        .to_html()
     ) for x in data]
], dtype="object")
df.style.set_table_styles([
    {"selector": ".matrix", "props": "position: relative;"},
    {"selector": ".matrix:before, .matrix:after", 
     "props":  'content: ""; position: absolute; top: 0; border: 1px solid #000; width: 6px; height: 100%;'
    },
    {"selector": ".matrix:before", "props": "left: -0px; border-right: -0;"},
    {"selector": ".matrix:after", "props": "right: -0px; border-left: 0;"}
])
display(df)
```

You can see the results here:
[Wrong_Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLHoh.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I cannot appreciate enough **@Attack69** helps. The following solution is solely done by the help of him. I just made one simple edit, after I understood the difference between Styler and DataFrame perfectly explained by **@Attack69**.

The solution seems to be pretty simply, we only need to use `display(df.style)` instead of `display(df)`

Again, I have no idea how long it would take me to come up with the solution with out the help of @Attack68. Thanks for helping me out with my basic questions. I am pretty much new in this area.

Answer (score 0):

`df` is a `DataFrame` class object.

`df.style` returns a `Styler` class object.

`df.style.some_style_function()` also returns a `Styler` class object.

When the last item returned in a Jupyter Notebook is a `Styler` object which has an `_repr_html_()` method, that is called and the resulting HTML
is displayed in the cell.

When you call `display(df)` you are essentially calling `df._repr_html_()` and that is obviously not the same as `df.style.some_styler_function()._repr_html_()` becuase they are different python objects.

Additionally `df._repr_html_()` has a column width trimming option meaning the cells have `...` at the end which prevents the HTML from properly rendering. You can turn that off if you review the documentation for `pandas.options`.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I could clearly understand what is the difference between DataFrame and Styler after your explanation, however when I added the `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)`, I got the following results:[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AgIi.png), which is basically the extended previously codes, and have not complied yet. @Attack68

Comment: @Attack69 hey man, I am not sure if it something normal or rude, I am pretty new to this platform. I just know you are extremely expert on this area, so was wondering if you can help me with my new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68941912/how-to-apply-pandas-set-option-python-to-pandas-style-objects). If you find this rude, lmk and I will stop bothering you. You have helped me more than enough so far, so i'm more than grateful for your help. Cheers